Better method to adjust Z-score
I came across a question a few days back in an interview that, in a time series of something, let's say price, if there's a jump either side, the z-score immediately doesn't change or it stays stagnant when someone is using rolling mean or rolling standard deviation as historical relativity stays same. I want to know what we should do statistically to address this issue? 
Thank you!
